# Conditioning on vs. fixing a random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

I am confused by the following notation, seen used by a professor in a course I'm taking.  $p(X|Y)$ denotes the conditioning of a distribution over a random variable $X$ by $Y$ and $p(X;y)$ denotes the distribution over $X$ where some variable $y$ is fixed.  I haven't been able to find any references about the latter notation online, but ostensibly, it is implied that $y$ is not a random variable.  Is this correct?  Otherwise, if $y$ were a random variable, the two notations would be equivalent, correct?

EDIT:

Note that I did not mean that $y$ is a value taken by $Y$.  My choice of variable names was poor, but please treat $y$ as a completely separate variable from $Y$, where $y$ may or may not be a random variable.

Comment: A notation means whatever its user defines it to mean. ([Lewis Carroll got it right](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/12608-when-i-use-a-word-humpty-dumpty-said-in-rather)--and no surprise, because he was a mathematician.)  "The question is, which is to be master (you or the [notation]) — that’s all."

Answer (score 2):

In probability theory generally, and as is the case here, upper case letters are used to denote random variables, and lower case letters are used to denote a specific (numerical, i.e., fixed) value taken on by the random variable.  Hence, P(X=x) means the probability that the random variable X has the value x.

So in your question, y denotes a specific, i.e., fixed, value taken on by the random variable Y.

If you don't like this convention, and think that it is too easy to confuse upper and lower case letters, don't blame me, I did not create it.

Comment: There is also a major school of thought that thinks of $p(X;y)$ as the distribution of $X$ when a certain parameter has value $y$, and vehemently disputes that $y$ can be considered to be the value taken on by a random variable $Y$: there is _no_ taint of randomness that can ever be a blemish on the purity of $y$ as a real number unrelated to any random variable.

Comment: There are many possible conventions,. I described the "conventional" convention, which quite obviously is the one used by the poster's professor.

Comment: In response to the edit in the original question. I explained what clearly seemed to be your professor's intention based on what you provided. If that is not what the professor provided and you wish help in interpreting what the professor provided, then you should provide it "unadulterated". I am guessing my interpretation is still correct, and you are allowing yourself to get confused by  Dilip Sarwate's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I've always understood the semicolon as delimiting random variables from distribution parameters. For example, the normal distribution is parameterized by mean and variance. I think this notation just allows you to talk about the parameters as variables, and discuss or alter their impact on the distribution of the random variables in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

In the situations that I've seen, $p(X; y)$ is used in cases when $y$ is not a random variable, but some other parameter (constant, variable, etc., doesn't matter) on which you don't define a distribution.

You may also use the notation $p_y(X)$ instead of $p(X; y)$.  As a concrete example: Consider a distribution $p(X=x;y) \propto \exp(-y\; x^2)$, where $y$ is some constant parameter.

It was confusing at first, but you will get used to it.